# Should it take longer to train a network with multiple outputs in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I'm using Keras for a task that has one main target and several optional targets.  When I train against all targets (and so have multiple outputs), it takes the same amount of time per epoch as when training with the single target/output.  Shouldn't we expect it to take somewhat longer in the multi-target scenario?

Answer (score 0):

This generally depends on how big is the output layer. In theory, more neurons to the output layer mean a bigger transition matrix (i.e weights, when assuming MLP), which means that the backpropagation should calculate derivatives with respect to more values, but when these values are relatively small to begin with I presume there wouldn't be much difference

Comment: The network is on the order of 1M weights.  Going from 1 output to 20 outputs doesn't affect the total size much, but shouldn't it cause a 20x increase in the error calculation for each weight as the error from each output is back propagated?  And isn't that a significant part of the computation?  I'm seeing perhaps a 10% increase in run time while I was expecting something like 10x.

Comment: I think you're correct regarding the error, but generally speaking, if you'd think of your weights as a vector with 1M elements, adding 19 more outputs (which is order of 19 weights in total, when considering fully contention to the previous layers) wouldn't add much in total (Again, compared to 1mil you're adding way fewer weights. unless your one from last layer has 10^5 neurons)

Comment: You are correct in that it isn't adding many weights, but the error backpropagation must be done for each output.  This means a 20x increase in computation for calculating errors for and updating all of the weights in the network.  Does Keras have some way to do this gracefully in parallel or something?

Comment: The gradients of the hidden layers are just summed (or averaged, depending on how the overall loss is calculated) over all outputs. After this is done, the computations are the same as with a single loss/output.